# Angular: $locationChangeSuccess fires before $destroy

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller where I'm reading query-string values set from a parent scope.  Because it is a parent scope updating the location, $scope.$on does not work, and $rootScope.$on must be used.  I was having an issue where the listener was called even though I created a destructor.  I fixed the issue by adding the line `if ($location.path() != '/gumby') return;`, although I don't like that it now has intimate knowledge of the path.

Besides modifying the parent scope by adding a $scope.$broadcast call, is there a better way to manage these events from this controller?

```
var listeners = [];

var listener = $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function () {
  if ($location.path() != '/gumby') return;

  #Do some stuff

  }
});

listeners.push(listener);

$scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
  removeWatchers();
});

function removeWatchers() {
  for (var i = 0; i < listeners.length; i++) {
    var listener = listeners[i];
    if (listener) {
      listener()
    }
  }
}
```